# Laravel - pass data from a function to another route's function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

**Current set-up:**

At the moment, a user can search that calls the post route. It then returns various things based on the search to the route `search.results` where it's displayed in the URL as `place/town`.

How can I pass over the `lat` and `lng` variables form the `search` function to the `showResults` function. I have tried `->with()` which returns null, and  also including them in the current array of `[$place, $town]` but they're then included in the URL.

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('search', 'Controller@search')->name('search');
Route::get('{place}/{town}', 'Controller@showResults')->name('search.results');
```

**Controller:**

Search function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $place =$request->get('name');
    $lat = $request->get('lat');
    $lng = $request->get('lng');

    return redirect()->route('search.results', [$place, $town]);
}
```

showResults function (empty at the moment):

```
public function showResults()
{
  // I want to use lat and lng here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Laravel Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#retrieving-data).

```
return redirect()
    ->route('search.results', [$place, $town])
    ->with('lng', $lng)
    ->with('lat', $lat);
```

And in your fonction

```
public function showResults(Request $request)
{
     $lat = $request->session()->get('lat');
     $lng = $request->session()->get('lng');
}
```

Comment: I was very close! Thank you. Would there be any reason why my latitude value won't send over - `"-1.5490773999999874"` That's what shows when I `dd()` the variable within the `search` function, but it returns `null` in `showResults`. The longitude works perfectly?

Comment: how do you send your two variables ? You can chain multiple `with` like that `->with('lat', $lat)->with('lng', $lng);`

Comment: Multiple `->with()` worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!